# Redondear numeros decimales python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero redondear números decimales de esta manera: 7.7 -> 7.5         o  7.4 -> 7.0
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Que intentaste?

Comment: Si deseas una respuesta, adjunta lo que has intentado (**código**). Saludos.

Comment: intente usar round pero solo redondea al entero mas cercano, para el 7.4 funcionaria round pero yo quisiera redondear 7.7 a 7.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si te he entendido correctamente, lo que pretendes es redondear hacia abajo pero en bloques de 0,50.

Una posible solución es jugar con la función int(). Me explico:

Usando int() python se queda el numero entero y se olvida de los decimales. Por ejemplo: int(7.7) -> 7
Esto te podría valer si quisieras saltos de 1,00. Pero como necesitas saltos de de 0,5, lo único que se me ocurre de forma fácil es multiplicar y dividir por 2, antes y después de la función int.
Ejemplo:

```
int(7.7*2)/2 -> 7.5
int(7.4*2)/2 -> 7.0
```

El uso de numero 2 es porque tienes que forzar un salto de 0.5, con lo cual 1/0.5 = 2.
Generalizando esta formula:

```
int(valor*(1/salto))/(1/salto)
```

Si lo vas a usar una única vez lo puedes escribir tal cual, pero si lo vas hacer de forma repetitiva, deberías crear una función para ello.

Ejemplo función:

```
def redondear_abajo_por_bloques(valor, salto):
    return int(valor*(1/salto))/(1/salto)
```

y luego llamar a la función:

```
redondear_abajo_por_bloques(7.7, 0.5) -> 7.5
redondear_abajo_por_bloques(7.4, 0.5) -> 7.0
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias :3